# ADO task download vs DownloadPipelineArtifact@2

Tags: azure-devops, download, azure-pipelines, ado, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am setting up a build job that needs to be triggered by another build pipeline.

```
trigger:
- main

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: triggeredpipeline # Name of the pipeline resource.
    source: <pipeline path and name> # The name of the pipeline referenced by this pipeline resource.
    project: <ADO project name> # Required only if the source pipeline is in another project
    trigger: true # Run app-ci pipeline when any run of security-lib-ci completes

pool: Default
```

Next step is to get artifacts from the triggering job to do the magic in the triggered build job.

Now I run into the situation that ADO 'download' (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-download?view=azure-pipelines) allows me to reuse the pipeline reference, but does not allow me to explicitly specify the target location.

```
  - download: triggeredpipeline  # pipeline resource identifier.
    displayName: Download files from triggering pipeline
    artifact: Platform
```

It will, like stated in the documentation, write it to `$(Pipeline.Workspace)/<pipeline resource identifier>/<artifact name>` , e.g. /triggeredpipeline/Platform (or content in Platform)

Now the documentation states that `download` is a shorthand for DownloadPipelineArtifact@2, and according to that documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/download-pipeline-artifact-v2?view=azure-pipelines) it is possible to specify a `targetPath`. What I do not see / understand how I can reuse my pipeline reference. I can only set the ids of the project and pipeline triggering my build.

```
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  inputs:
    buildType: 'specific'
    project: '<uuid>'
    definition: '266'
    buildVersionToDownload: 'latest'
    artifactName: 'Platform'
    targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

So how can I use my reference to my trigger ( `pipeline: triggeredpipeline`) but still being able to define what the target folder is.

(and yes, I could add some task that does the copy, but the size of the source artifact is considerable so downloading, then again moving / copying it is a waste of time)

I hope one of you have worked with triggered build pipelines before and know a way to reuse the trigger reference to download the artifact(s) to the right spot in 1 go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use metadata listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/resources-pipelines-pipeline?view=azure-pipelines#pipeline-resource-metadata-as-predefined-variables)

```
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.projectName
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.projectID
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.pipelineName
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.pipelineID
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.runName
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.runID
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.runURI
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.sourceBranch
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.sourceCommit
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.sourceProvider
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.requestedFor
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.requestedForID
```

And combine them with `DownloadPipelineArtifact@2`

```
  - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
    inputs:
      buildType: 'specific'
      project: '$(resources.pipeline.triggeredpipeline.projectID)'
      definition: '$(resources.pipeline.triggeredpipeline.pipelineID)'
      specificBuildWithTriggering: true
      buildVersionToDownload: 'specific'
      pipelineId: '$(resources.pipeline.triggeredpipeline.runID)'
      artifactName: 'Platform'
      targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

Comment: Thank both for clarifying

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `specificBuildWithTriggering` flag.

From the documentation:

> Alias: preferTriggeringPipeline. Optional. Use when source == specific. When appropriate, download artifacts from the triggering build.

Comment: But that still required specifying Project Name.

Comment: This 
```
  - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
    displayName: Download files from triggering pipeline
    inputs:
      buildType: 'specific'
      specificBuildWithTriggering: true
      artifactName: 'Platform'
      targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

Comment: Results in this error
```
##[debug]TargetPath: C:\fgrbuildagent1\_work\1009\a
##[debug]ArtifactName: Platform
##[debug]BuildResult: Succeeded
##[debug]Run: Specific
##[error]Project Name (Parameter 'notFound:CannotBeNullOrEmpty')
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]Project Name (Parameter 'notFound:CannotBeNullOrEmpty')
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]
```